# Javascript regex parenthesized submatch array

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to get submatches as an array instead of arguments?

Like this:

```
text.replace(/^(?!(^$)|\<(h[0-9])\>)(.*)$/mg, function(match, submatches) {
    return '<p>'+submatches[2]+'</p>';
});
```

instead of this:

```
text.replace(/^(?!(^$)|\<(h[0-9])\>)(.*)$/mg, function(match, p1, p2, p3) {
    return '<p>'+p3+'</p>';
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript has a special object that is passed into each function call called [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments).

```
function(match) {
    var submatches = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
}
```

This works on older versions of Javascript, while the [`rest parameter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) operator is only available in ES6.

Answer (score 2):

You could aggregate all arguments into single array of arguments with rest operator:

```
text.replace(/^(?!(^$)|\<(h[0-9])\>)(.*)$/mg, function(match, ...submatches) {
    return '<p>' + submatches[2] + '</p>';
});
```

Comment: Beware that `submatches` will contain more than just submatches in your example. `.replace` passes weird things to your function.